# Rails - ActiveRecord Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model-associations

This was working just fine, not sure what broke it, but now I'm getting this error:

```
undefined method `Name' for nil:NilClass
```

I'm running Rails 3.1.  I have a table called "restaurants", "lists", and "list_Items". The associations are as follows:

```
class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
  #relations
  has_many :list_items
  has_many :reviews

class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :list_items, :dependent => :destroy

class ListItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :restaurant
  belongs_to :list
```

The line that's giving me the problem is in the view partial that displays my list items

```
<tr>
  <td><%= list_item.restaurant.Name %> <%= link_to 'X', list_item, :method => :delete, :remote => true %></td>
</tr>
```

I think this should all work fine, but given the error at top, it's not recongizing the association such that I can get at the restaurant name.  Again, this was working, I don't know why it's breaking now...

### UPDATE

As Mu correctly pointed out (thanks Mu), the problem isn't the association, it was the presence of a list_item associated with a deleted restaurant. So, it was running up against a Nil entry.

The above is resolved and now the real question (the question I should have been asking to begin with) is how to ensure this doesn't happen. What should I change to ensure that a list_item is deleted when the associated restaurant is deleted?

Comment: If the associations weren't working you'd get an "undefined method" error of some sort when trying to call `list_item.restaurant`, not a  `nil`. Have you checked your database to make sure that all of your ListItems really do have Restaurants associated with them and that all the IDs are valid?

Comment: This is probably not the error you're running into now, but I expect it'll be one you run into later - `list_item.restaurant.Name` should actually be `list_item.restaurant.name`, with a lower-case 'n' in name. Otherwise, Mu's comment is right on the money, I think.

Comment: You're right, that was the problem. I had deleted one of the restaurants and it was getting stuck on the missing record. What should I add in here so that doesn't happen? That is, when a restaurant is deleted, it should also delete any associated list_items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :list_items, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :reviews
  ...

end
```

And you are good to go.

Comment: Ha! I saw your answer and went, well duh, I already have that in there. But I looked at the model file and, sure enough, I had forgotten to add the :dependent => destroy. Thanks man, I'm banging my head on the wall with how stupid this all was!

Comment: It happens all the time and with everyone, the tiniest piece what we assume is there, is the source of errors. :)